# Stopping a long while function exactly where it is, without letting it run to the end

Tags: python

So I want to be clear what the difference is between this question and all other questions:

I want to break out of a long while function, that starts like this:

```
while running:
    framerate += 1.0
    if Counter > 0.0:
```

But I don't want to just use `running=False` to stop it, because then the last while loop that already has been triggered will still finish and run to the end.
I need this to fine-tune the framerate, so the loop has to stop right there where it is in the while loop and restart from the beginning.

And since the while loop is really long I really don't want to add a

```
if running==False:
       break
```

to EVERY single expression in the while loop.

Is there any way I can get out of the while loop right where it is at the moment without adding dozens of break expressions to it?

Here if you want an example of the while code:

````
running=True

while running:
    framerate += 1.0
    if Counter > 0.0:
        SetCounter()
    elif Counter == 0.0:
        newframerate += 1
        Counter = -1.0
        #Check for collisions:
        for enemy in enemies:
            for bullet in bullets:
                if enemy.Collides(bullet):
                    if enemy.state=="damaged":
                        enemy.lt(random.randint(-10,10))
                    else:
                        enemy.state="damaged"
                        enemy.speed=0.15
                        enemy.shapesize(0.5, 0.5, 10)
                        enemy.color("black")
                    bullet.status="ready"
                    bullet.ht()
                    Sparks.explode(enemy)
            if(enemy.Collides(spaceship)):
                if enemy.state=="whole":
                    if not triggerexplosiononce:
                        restart=True
                        Sparks.explode(spaceship)
                        triggerexplosiononce=True
                elif enemy.state=="damaged":
                    metal+=1
                    enemy.ht()
                    enemy.state="done"
                    enemy.setposition(10000,10000)
                    size+=0.05
                    spaceship.shapesize(size,size*1.4, 1)
                    if exhaustoffset<15:
                        exhaustoffset+=0.05
                        exhaustoffset*=1.4
                    else:
                        exhaustoffset+=0.1
                    #gun.shapesize(size*1.4,size*0.3, 1)
                    shipwindow.shapesize(size*0.3,size*0.3, 1)
        #Speed up the game:
        window.update()
        #automatically MOVE THE ENEMY
        for enemy in enemies:
            if enemy.isvisible():# and enemy.state=="whole":
                enemy.move()
        #Move the bullet
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet.move()

        #Gun Rotation (gun used as fire exhaust for now
        #if keyboard.is_pressed("c"):# and keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
            #gun.Turn("Left")
        #if keyboard.is_pressed("v"):# and keyboard.is_pressed("Ctrl"):
            #gun.Turn("Right")

        #Reset Once functionality
        if  spaceship.xcor()>-349 and spaceship.xcor()<349 \
        and spaceship.ycor()>-349 and spaceship.ycor()<349:
            Once=False
        #Breaks
        if keyboard.is_pressed("b") and spaceship.speed>0.1:# and keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
            spaceship.deccelerate(4)

        #SPACESHIP MOVEMENT
        if spaceship.xcor()>-350 and spaceship.xcor()<350 \
        and spaceship.ycor()>-350 and spaceship.ycor()<350:
            #Rotate the Spaceship
            if keyboard.is_pressed("Left"):
                spaceship.Turn("Left")
                #Drone Bullet Experiment
                #bullet.Turn("Left")

            if keyboard.is_pressed("Right"):
                spaceship.Turn("Right")
                # Drone Bullet Experiment
                #bullet.Turn("Right")

            #Motor
            if keyboard.is_pressed("Up"):
                gun.showturtle()
                if spaceship.speed<-0.1*spaceship.speedlimit:
                    spaceship.accelerate(4)
                elif spaceship.speed >= -0.1*spaceship.speedlimit and spaceship.speed <0.0:
                    spaceship.speed=0.1*spaceship.speedlimit
                elif spaceship.speed<spaceship.speedlimit:
                    spaceship.accelerate()
                if  spaceship.xcor()>-349 and spaceship.xcor()<349 \
                and spaceship.ycor()>-349 and spaceship.ycor()<349:
                    spaceship.fd(spaceship.speed)
                else:
                    if Once==False:
                        Once=True
                    spaceship.fd(spaceship.speed/spaceship.speedlimit)

            elif keyboard.is_pressed("Down"):
                gun.hideturtle()
                if spaceship.speed>0.1*spaceship.speedlimit:
                    spaceship.deccelerate(4)
                elif spaceship.speed <= 0.1*spaceship.speedlimit and spaceship.speed >0.0:
                    spaceship.speed=-0.1*spaceship.speedlimit
                elif spaceship.speed>-spaceship.speedlimit:
                    spaceship.deccelerate()
                if  spaceship.xcor()>-349 and spaceship.xcor()<349 \
                and spaceship.ycor()>-349 and spaceship.ycor()<349:
                    spaceship.fd(spaceship.speed)
                else:
                    if Once==False:
                        Once=True
                    spaceship.fd(spaceship.speed/spaceship.speedlimit)

            elif spaceship.speed>0.1*spaceship.speedlimit or spaceship.speed<-0.1*spaceship.speedlimit:
                gun.hideturtle()
                if spaceship.speed>0.1*spaceship.speedlimit:
                    spaceship.deccelerate()
                elif spaceship.speed<-0.1*spaceship.speedlimit:
                    spaceship.accelerate()
                if spaceship.xcor() > -349 and spaceship.xcor() < 349 \
                and spaceship.ycor() > -349 and spaceship.ycor() < 349:
                    spaceship.fd(spaceship.speed)
                else:
                    if Once == False:
                        Once = True
                        # spaceship.speed = 0.1
                    spaceship.fd(spaceship.speed / spaceship.speedlimit)

        #Autorotation against borders
        elif spaceship.xcor()<-349:
            spaceship.setx(-349)
            if keyboard.is_pressed("Right")==False and spaceship.heading()>180 and spaceship.heading()<270:
                spaceship.lt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)
            elif keyboard.is_pressed("Left")==False and spaceship.heading()<180 and spaceship.heading()>90:
                spaceship.rt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)
        elif spaceship.xcor()>349:
            spaceship.setx(349)
            if keyboard.is_pressed("Right")==False and spaceship.heading()>0 and spaceship.heading()<90:
                spaceship.lt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)
            elif keyboard.is_pressed("Left")==False and spaceship.heading()<360 and spaceship.heading()>270:
                spaceship.rt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)
        elif spaceship.ycor()<-349:
            spaceship.sety(-349)
            if keyboard.is_pressed("Right")==False and spaceship.heading()>270 or spaceship.heading()<90:
                spaceship.lt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)
            elif keyboard.is_pressed("Left")==False:
                spaceship.rt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)
        elif spaceship.ycor()>349:
            spaceship.sety(349)
            if keyboard.is_pressed("Right")==False and spaceship.heading()>90 and spaceship.heading()<270:
                spaceship.lt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)
            elif keyboard.is_pressed("Left")==False:
                spaceship.rt(1*spaceship.speedlimit)

        #keyboard.on_press_key("q", Do)
        #keyboard.on_release_key("q", Do)

        #Teleportation Grow effect of the Beamer window:
        if dummygrow==True and growcounter<10:
            dummylengths+=0.05
            dummy.turtlesize(dummylengths,dummylengths,1)
            growcounter+=1
        elif dummygrow==True and growcounter>9:
            dummylengths=0.3
            growcounter=0
        elif dummygrow==False:
            pass

        #Explosion: Move the sparks:

        if Sparks.sparksmoving==True and movecounter < 25:
            movesparks()
            movecounter+=1
        elif Sparks.sparksmoving==True and movecounter>24:
            Sparks.sparksmoving=False
            movecounter=0
            for spark in sparksgroup:
                spark.ht()
                if restart==True:
                    spaceship.setposition(0, 0)
                    spaceship.setheading(90)
                    spaceship.speed=0
                    for enm in enemies:
                        if enm.isvisible():
                            enm.showturtle()
                            enm.setposition(random.randint(-349, 349), random.randint(-349, 349))
                            if enm.xcor()<50 and enm.xcor()>-50\
                            and enm.ycor()<50 and enm.ycor()>-50:
                                enm.fd(100)
                    triggerexplosiononce=False
                    restart=False

        #Gun and Window Follow Position and Rotation:
        gun.setheading(spaceship.heading())
        gun.setposition(spaceship.xcor(),spaceship.ycor())
        gun.fd(-exhaustoffset)
        shipwindow.setposition(spaceship.xcor(),spaceship.ycor())

        Once=False
        Counter=Delay```
````

Comment: Can you add a comment to every section you want to jump out of the while-loop in you code?

Comment: How do you plan on indicating that you want the loop to end?  How will that indicator be set?

Comment: Please provide minimal code

Comment: I don't want to add a comment to every section I want to jump out of, because it is very time-consuming. That's the whole point of this post, if you read what it says. I know how to add a break to every point of the while loop to exit on command. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I want to indicate that the loop ends by setting a timer. So when the timer runs out, the 'while loop' should stop executing right at the point where it is, instead of running till the end.
So just setting running to False when the timer runs out won't help.

Comment: There may be a bit of confusion about your question: a) under what condition do you want to break, and b) where is that condition tested? Respondents here seem to think you want to check for a condition at a myriad of places in the code, and break right there. Hence they asked to comment in the code where that may be. But you seem to indicate that you want to break out based on an independent timer. That's a different animal. Could you confirm?

Comment: Confirmed, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want too much code, you can eliminate the `while running`, and use `while True`, and instead of `if running == False: break`, only use `break`. *(Sorry if this doesn't help)*

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's the same thing if I use True or running. I use running for a specific reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot get around
a) determining the break condition
b) breaking if it is met

Your approach is to break by setting a flag and then checking the flag at the while (or repeat) end of the loop.

I don't see a "running" flag being set in the loop snippet you provide, so it's hard to provide a code-specific example for your case, but perhaps this will do:

You can break from the loop without setting a break flag: simply state "break" if the condition is met:

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html

You can also put the loop in a function and do an early "return" upon detecting the break condition. This cleans up your scope nicely by removing all temporary variables.

And you can put your loop in an iterator and raise a StopIteration exception to signal the end of the iteration

https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/exceptions.html

But in all cases, you cannot get around checking a condition in every spot where it matters, and then execution a break or stop or return.

What sometimes works, and if your loop is very long, you can re-factor your code to end up with fewer spots where you perform the check.

Comment: Thanks for your insights.
Oh yeah, that was just a typo. I added the 'while running' to the sample script.

Would you be able to give an example on how to use the break statement?
Yeah, re-factoring the code might be a smart plan B.
So you don't think there is a way to stop the while loop execution right where it is at the moment?
Would you know if there is a way to terminate the current execution of a function at any given point? Same thing, that it does not continue to execute the function till the end?

Comment: The code should break basically each time before any object is being moved or changes position or visibility. As you can tell, there are dozens of them in the script, so I want to find a different way than flagging all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a thread for this. start a thread to do the loop thing, and stop when time up.
reference to this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems to be addressing kind of what I'm looking for. I will take a deeper look into it.

Answer (score 1):

From our discussion in the comments, I believe you want to break out from a loop based on an independent timer outside the loop.

Also, you did not want to  determine a break/return condition within the loop (at several spots in the loop code) and break/return immediately, or by setting a flag that is checked as the loop condition.

User beware: killing a process or thread requires careful examination of any wreckage left behind (open connections, occupied resources, blocking/locking etc...). In this case I am not aware of any, so -at least for starters- this should do:

```
import multiprocessing as m
import time

def looper():
  i = 0
  while True:
    print "a) i="+str(i)
    time.sleep(4)
    print "b) i="+str(i)
    time.sleep(4)
    i += 1

p = m.Process(target=looper)
p.daemon = True

print "starting"
p.start()
time.sleep(9)
p.terminate()

print "done"
```

Output:

```
starting
a) i=0
b) i=0
a) i=1
done
```

If you run this, be aware that it takes 9 seconds to get this output.

In stead of a timer, you can also use a different external condition to terminate.

Notice how the loop was interrupted within the loop code (between step a and b), not at the end or start of the loop code, as is usually the case with a repeat or while flag. Also, the loop has no break conditions within it, and there are no signal or flag checks within the loop. I believe this is what you were after.

Multi-processing is different from Threads, and I suggest you look into the difference to make sure this suits your case and overall application.

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample script.
That is in theory exactly what I am looking for.
I will do more experiments with it, to see how effectively and with what results I can implement it into the project. 
Btw., I had to add ```if __name__ == '__main__':``` to the script to make it work.
What system/platform are you using so that you don't need write brackets for print commands? (I write ```print ("done")``` for example. Is that a different python version you use?

Comment: You are welcome. I was always interested in the multi-processing / threading in python and took it as an opportunity for some  deeper R&D. My version: Mac OS X 10.14.6 comes with Python 2.7.16.

Comment: Oh yeah, the difference in scripting is because of your Python version, and because you use Mac. So, the main problem I have right now when using multiprocessing is that it opens a new turtle window each time I run a process via multiprocess.
Here is a test game I created for this, just to test this out.
Only the multiprocess test part:
https://pastebin.com/K1gu3JCQ
Full version of the game (requires you to import custom images into the game project folder):
https://pastebin.com/YDPgWTUd
I tried printing to the console via process, moving the jumper to the right, and setting window size.

Comment: @SebastianStoica-Florea For starters, did you get the sample code above to work?

Comment: Yes, I could make it work. (I had to change it for the version I use, with brackets and as I already mentioned, adding the `if __name__ == '__main__':` expression (which would look like this: https://pastebin.com/hSSy7vk0).
But let's say I add only one turtle to the script, then it immediately opens two turtle windows.
Here is a very simple example. I tried to make a version that works on your system:
https://pastebin.com/S6zrCCVD

Comment: I assumed that it would be difficult to improve.
I read that the multiprocessing is difficult to use within only one turtle window, because of how the turtle module works.
Also there will be similar complications using the threading module.

I might come back to this and change the turtle module when I have a better understanding of python, or experiment with different methods meanwhile.
I appreciate your help.